# Are there any risks to using crib bumpers?

Tags: safety

Crib bumpers are widely advertised, and sometimes sold with cribs.

Are there any risks to their use?

Comment: Related... http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/6504/11940

Answer (score 8):

The APP says no crib bumpers

http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/early/2011/10/12/peds.2011-2284.full.pdf+html

See page 1034

> Because there is no evidence that bumper pads or similar products that
>   attach to crib slats or sides prevent injury in young infants and
>   because there is the potential for suffocation, entrapment, and
>   strangulation, these products are not recommended

Answer (score 4):

The main risk comes from suffocation of the child.  This [form of death is increasing.](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/303085.php)

> a new study reveals that the number of infant deaths and injuries resulting from crib bumpers has significantly increased in recent years. And researchers are warning parents that they should never, ever be used.

Some US states [have banned crib bumpers](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/303085.php).

> In 2013, the state of Maryland banned their sale, led by the city of Chicago, which first did in 2011.

When the child is older there's perhaps some risk that they climb on the crib bumper, which means they could fall out of the crib.

Crib bumpers were originally introduced to protect children from wide gaps in-between crib bars.  Those wide gaps no longer exist, and so there is no reason to continue using crib bumpers.